# Trying to add additional page to Jekyll site

Tags: html, ruby, templates, jekyll

I recently set up my new blog / portfolio site using Jekyll. The theme I customized only had the home page which was also the posts page and then an about me page.

I am trying to add a new page, projects, that will be similar to the home page, but will list out projects just like the posts are listed out on the home(index) page.

I am able to get the projects link to show in the nav bar and when I click it, it takes me to the correct URL. The rest of the template is there, but the example file that I have in the projects folder isn't showing. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my directory tree

```
├── CNAME
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── LICENSE
├── _config.yml
├── _includes
│   ├── analytics.html
│   └── head.html
├── _layouts
│   ├── about.html
│   ├── default.html
│   ├── post.html
│   └── project.html
├── _posts
│   ├── 2017-03-09-developer-goals.md
│   ├── 2017-03-09-finding-web-dev.md
│   ├── 2017-03-09-my-experience.md
│   ├── 2017-09-16-example-content.md
│   └── 2017-09-17-jumping-into-react.md
├── _projects
│   └── 2017-03-09-developer-goals.md
├── _sass
│   ├── _base.scss
│   ├── _catalogue.scss
│   ├── _code.scss
│   ├── _layout.scss
│   ├── _pagination.scss
│   ├── _post.scss
│   ├── _syntax.scss
│   └── _variables.scss
├── _site
│   ├── 2017-03-09
│   │   ├── developer-goals.html
│   │   ├── finding-web-dev.html
│   │   └── my-experience.html
│   ├── 2017-09-16
│   │   └── example-content.html
│   ├── 2017-09-17
│   │   └── jumping-into-react.html
│   ├── CNAME
│   ├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── about
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── favicon.ai
│   ├── favicon.png
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── project
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── styles.css
├── about.md
├── favicon.ai
├── favicon.png
├── index.html
├── projects.html
└── styles.scss
```

Here is my `projects.html` file

```
---
layout: default
title: "Projects"
author: "Steven"
permalink: /project/
---

<div class="catalogue">
  {% for project in paginator.project %}
    <a href="{{ project.url | prepend: site.url }}" class="catalogue-item">
      <div>
        <time datetime="{{ project.date }}" class="catalogue-time">{{ project.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}</time>
        <h1 class="catalogue-title">{{ project.title }}</h1>
        <div class="catalogue-line"></div>

        <p>
          {{ project.content | truncatewords: 30 | strip_html }}
        </p>

      </div>
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path | prepend: site.url }}" class="left arrow">&#8592;</a>
  {% endif %}
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path | prepend: site.url }}" class="right arrow">&#8594;</a>
  {% endif %}

  <span>{{ paginator.page }}</span>
</div>
```

Here is my `project.html` file:

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="post">

  <h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title }}</h1>
  <div class="post-line"></div>

  {{ content }}

</div>
```

This layout and design is super simple, but just can't figure out why this isn't working. Any help is much appreciated! Also feel free to check out the site live, stevenmills.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders that start with an underscore are special for Jekyll. In this case it seems that `_projects` isn't a collection or something else, so it will be ignored by Jekyll.

Remove the leading underscore and add a `_posts` folder inside:

```
projects/_posts/2017-03-09-developer-goals.md
```

Then the `2017-03-09-developer-goals.md` post would have the `projects` category too.